# How to save larger files using Mongo CLI

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use the mongo CLI to save a larger-than-usual JSON (using db.mycollection.save(...)) but the mongo command line doesn't accept the full length of the JSON (I believe the length limit accepted by the command line is 4096, which is shorter than my JSON).

Is there another way to save this JSON to Mongo, using native functionality from the mongo CLI? (I am trying to do this by invoking mongo commands from a bash script)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this difficulty, I solved it by calling

> eval "mongo myJsFile.js"

instead of

> mongo < myJsFile.js

in the bash script